# how can my web application accessible to 10 users at a same time?

Tags: asp.net

how can my web application accessible to 10 users at a same time??

please explain (interview question)

(session object, application object , global.asax events)

Comment: Ask your "interview queszion" here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/
Have a look at this meta-link to see the differences of both platforms: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-so

Comment: @Tim - it's better to link the the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erm....the best answer to your question would be to:

**Host it on the Internet**

Based on your question that really is the only answer, if I was given that interview question I'd ask for clarification as I am you.

Comment: Of course, hosting it on the Internet would make it available to far more than 10 users at a time.

Comment: Are you saying that the OP wants the web application to be only accessible to a maximum of 10 at a time?